# Fusion charts - msline chart using JSON with database

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts, fusioncharts

I am trying to produce a msline chart in Fusion Charts using JSON and php to import my data from my database, but am having trouble plotting the data which means the chart is not displaying properly.

View output here:  www.waflfootyfacts.net/charttest2.php

My database example is like this;

```
|Team |RoundNo | Total
|East Perth | R1 | 41 
|East Fremantle | R1 | 96
|East Perth | R2 | 109 
|Swan Districts | R2 | 96
|East Perth | R3 | 115 
|Subiaco | R3 | 51
```

What I need the chart to produce is the RoundNo on the x axis and two dataseries one for "East Perth" with values 41, 109 and 115 and a second series called "Opponent" with values of 96,96, and 51.

My chart is generating but not calculating the series correctly.

My code

```
// Form the SQL query

   $strQueryCategories = "SELECT RoundNo FROM MatchDetails  WHERE (Team = 'East Perth' OR Opponent = 'East Perth') AND Season = 2015 AND RoundNo IN ('R1', 'R2', 'R3')";

$resultCategories = $dbhandle->query($strQueryCategories)or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

$strQueryData = "SELECT Team, RoundNo, Total FROM MatchDetails  WHERE (Team = 'East Perth' OR Opponent = 'East Perth') AND Season = 2015 AND RoundNo IN ('R1', 'R2', 'R3')";


$resultData = $dbhandle->query($strQueryData)or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

if ($resultData) {

    $arrData = array(
        "chart" => array(
            "caption" => "East Perth in 2015",
            "subcaption" => "Scores For & Against",
            "theme" => "fint"
        )
    );

    $arrData["categories"] = array(array("category" => array()));


    if ($resultCategories) {
        $controlBreakValue = "";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCategories)) {
            if ($controlBreakValue != $row["RoundNo"]) {
                $controlBreakValue = $row["RoundNo"];
                array_push( $arrData["categories"][0]["category"], array("label" => $controlBreakValue));
                $controlBreakValue == "";
            }
        }
    }


    $arrData["dataset"] = array();
    $i = 0;
    if ($resultData) {
        $controlBreakValue = "";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultData)) {
           if ($controlBreakValue != $row["Team"]) {
               $controlBreakValue = $row["Team"];
               array_push($arrData["dataset"], array("seriesname" => $controlBreakValue, "data" => array(array("value" => $row["Total"]))));
               $controlBreakValue == "";
               $i++;
                   }  
            array_push($arrData["dataset"][$i - 1]["data"], array("value" => $row["Total"]));

              }
            }
    }

$jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

$dbhandle->close();

echo $jsonEncodedData;

?>

<html>


   <body>
      <?php

        $columnChart = new FusionCharts("msline", "" , 300, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

            $columnChart->render();

      ?>

      <div id="chart-1"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is not with the chart but with your logic. From the implementation, you have created 3 series instead of two. Try create the structure of the data manually first and then match your logic.

Comment: thanks pallabB - I have done this already and cant seem to get it to work like I want to doing it this way.  I've edited my query and code above with no luck - I have based it on the 'Factory' example on fusion charts

Comment: This is how it should look - http://jsfiddle.net/BQUw4/61/

Comment: I've now managed to get it just about correct.  The only problem I am having now is the first value in each series is being duplicated as bothe the first and second value, the second value is showing as the third and the third value is not displaying on the chart at all

Comment: Since you have changed your logic its hard to guess, but from my experience, should be an issue on how you are iterating on the loops. Check the initialization and increment process in your loops closely.

Comment: The $arrData[dataset} has not changed form the above- my queries are both returning results as expected - yet the first value is still duplicating  - i'm no expert by any means and have no idea of what the loop is doing

Answer (score 0):

All sorted - ended up not being my error but the php wrapper provided by fusion charts was wrong - they sent me a new one and it worked!